# How to configure app.config with many connection strings to SQL database?

Tags: c#, sql, database

I have an application that should connect to many databases on different servers.
What is the best way to code it?

Comment: Are you interested in configuring the connection strings at runtime, i.e. add new connection strings and edit the existing ones, or only using some fixed connection strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using multiple add tag with  Different name inside ConnectionStrings tag  you can provide multiple connection string in app.config.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="name1" connectionString="Your connection1"  providerName="DataBaseProvider1" />
    <add name="name2" connectionString="Your connection2" providerName="DataBaseProvider2"  />
</connectionStrings>
```

To read connection string, use,

```
 string connection1 = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["name1"].ConnectionString
```

Answer (score 2):

You may add as many connection string as you want, like following:

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Name1" connectionString="ConnectionString1" providerName="DataBaseProvider" />
    <add name="Name2" connectionString="ConnectionString2" providerName="DataBaseProvider" />
    <add name="Name3" connectionString="ConnectionString3" providerName="DataBaseProvider" />
    <add name="Name4" connectionString="ConnectionString4" providerName="DataBaseProvider" />
    ....  
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

For more information on DataBaseProvider you may visit following links:
[.NET Framework Data Providers at msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6cd7c08.aspx)
[ADO.NET Data Providers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dd363565.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple settings:

```
<add key="server1_db1" value="here give connection string">
```

And then query them like:

```
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[
    System.Environment.MachineName + "_db1"];
```

That way you can set up different settings for different servers.

Comment: ConnectionStrings tag already there for adding multiple connection string.